# How Integrate Admob ads on Cordova in 2020?

Tags: cordova, admob, cordova-plugins, cordova-admob

I convert my html5 game to android studio project through Cordova and PhoneGap, please how I can integrate Admob ads on my project, all tutorial available not working in 2020.

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Did you try cordova-plugin-admob-simple? 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-admob-simple

Comment: yes I try this plugin and also free and pro one but without any results, the ads won't be showing.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Longs/cordova-plugin-ad-admob/ includes the ability to add the required flags for non-personalized ads where required for compliance with GDPR and CCPA

Comment: I don't understand well this documentation!

Answer (score 0):

use **cordova-plugin-admob-free** it's working perfect in 2020

check here in [github](https://github.com/ratson/cordova-plugin-admob-free)